# django-allauth facebook login issue with facebook accounts that is not connected to any email address

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, socialauth

I have a site where users have to login only using facebook.
Most of time it works fine. But sometimes, when user logins with facebook, it again asks for email address.

But I have a new issue. **Those facebook made with mobile number and not any email address connected to it are not able to login.**

**So how can i solve this problem ?**

**I am using django-allauth for social login.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my assumption but because facebook don't allow you to retrieve `phone_number` from GRAPH anymore it will use the blank email so you will have duplicate blank email if it pass
From the configuration docs https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

> SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP (=True)
>
> Attempt to bypass the signup form by using fields (e.g. username,
> email) retrieved from the social account provider. If a conflict
> arises due to a duplicate e-mail address the signup form will still
> kick in.

So the user are required to manually input the email address if they don't have email

My suggestion to this is using the signals of allauth save email with some kind of format for example `timestamp` with `pre_social_login` signals
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

Comment: Thank you @Linh Nguyen for reply.

But, I have a question that if "So the user are required to manually input the email address if they don't have email"  Can a user manually input any email address that is not connected to facebook account?

Comment: @AakashShakya from the logic of the docs, seems like it.

Comment: "So the user are required to manually input the email address if they don't have email"  seems to work.  But yeah using signals of allauth to save email email can be a good way.